# Multiplication in Python with arrays of different length

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multiplication

I have a five 100x100 arrays, A, and I want to multiply each matrix by a value from an array of length five, B. I wish to multiply the first matrix in A by the first value in B and the second matrix by the second value in B, etc. Am I able to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you have 5 different 100x100 arrays, consider using a for loop

Comment: when you say "array", do you mean that you're using `numpy`? when you say "five 100x100 arrays" do you mean 5 different arrays, each 100x100 or a single array with dimensions 5x100x100? If your answers are "yes" and "a single 5x100x100 array" then `A*B[:,None,None]` is the correct way to perform the multiplication that you've requested.

Comment: I have tried a loop but all five A matrices were only multiplied by the first element from B

Comment: They are five different arrays each 100x100

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer has been provided by gboffi in his comment. Yet I want to elaborate that answer, giving a concrete example with code:

```
import numpy as np

#example data, all arrays of ones 100x100
A1 = A2 = A3 =A4 = A5 = np.ones((100, 100))    

#example array containing the factor for each matrix
B = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

#create an array containing all matrices
A = np.array([A1, A2, A3, A4, A5])

A*B[:,None,None]
```

The result then looks like this:

```
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    ..., 
    [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

   [[ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    ..., 
    [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

   [[ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.],
    [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.],
    [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.],
    ..., 
    [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.],
    [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.],
    [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.]],

   [[ 4.,  4.,  4., ...,  4.,  4.,  4.],
    [ 4.,  4.,  4., ...,  4.,  4.,  4.],
    [ 4.,  4.,  4., ...,  4.,  4.,  4.],
    ..., 
    [ 4.,  4.,  4., ...,  4.,  4.,  4.],
    [ 4.,  4.,  4., ...,  4.,  4.,  4.],
    [ 4.,  4.,  4., ...,  4.,  4.,  4.]],

   [[ 5.,  5.,  5., ...,  5.,  5.,  5.],
    [ 5.,  5.,  5., ...,  5.,  5.,  5.],
    [ 5.,  5.,  5., ...,  5.,  5.,  5.],
    ..., 
    [ 5.,  5.,  5., ...,  5.,  5.,  5.],
    [ 5.,  5.,  5., ...,  5.,  5.,  5.],
    [ 5.,  5.,  5., ...,  5.,  5.,  5.]]])
```